# Send string without "\n" in Netty

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I have a simple socket client written in netty.io and for data sending and receiving I use `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`. and in Initializer class I defined this:

```
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
```

but in this way I need every time put "\n" new line symbol at the end of string which I needn't. without this symbol I can't send or receive any string data. what is the solution use string data in netty without new line delimiter?

Comment: Ok, you're saying your data isn't split into frames by newline, right? How *is* it split into frames, then?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify whatever delimiter you like, for instance

```
ByteBuf[] delimiters = new ByteBuf[] {
    Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\r', '\n' }), // WINDOWS
    Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\n' }),       // UNIX / OSX
    Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[] { '\r' })        // LEGACY MAC
};
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(MAXFRAMELENGTH, delimiters));
```

In this way, if you omit it, you can get rid of `\n` and replace with another character.

If you want to omit **any** delimiter, than I think you could use a [FixedLengthFrameDecoder](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FixedLengthFrameDecoder.html):
`pipeline.addLast("framer", new FixedLengthFrameDecoder(yourFrameLength));`
or a [LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) for more options.

Comment: how I can omit it? I write as you described and delete the \n from string, but it's not working

Comment: I added that to the response: if you want to remove any delimiter, you may try with FixedLengthFrameDecoder

Comment: my data will be dynamic and I can't use FixedLengthFrameDecoder :(

Comment: If you have a special need and you can neither rely on delimiter nor on fixed frame length, I think you are better off developing your own Decoder: you can develop your own version of a [FrameDecoder](https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html) that handles the special case. Basically just a modification of one of the decoders shipped with Netty source code.